# What is wrong with my code "vba"

Tags: vba, if-statement

When I run the code it generates a random number between 100 and 210 and I want my `j` to be valued as follows but it is not happening like that.

It generates numbers for `j` but it not according to conditions that I coded.

```
    Range("J12").Formula = "=RANDBETWEEN(100,210)"

x = Range("J12").Value


    If x < 109 And x >= 100 Then
j = 100

ElseIf x > 109 And x < 119 Then
    j = 110

ElseIf x > 119 And x < 129 Then
    j = 120

ElseIf x > 129 And x < 139 Then
    j = 130

ElseIf x > 139 And x < 149 Then
    j = 140

ElseIf x > 149 And x < 159 Then
    j = 150

ElseIf x > 159 And x < 169 Then
    j = 160

ElseIf x > 169 And x < 179 Then
    j = 170

ElseIf x > 179 And x < 189 Then
    j = 180

ElseIf x > 189 And x < 199 Then
    j = 190

Else: j = 200

    End If

Range("I12").Value = j
```

Comment: Is it your intention to introduce a bias in favor of the value 200? If not, why even bother with `J12` and instead just have the formula `=100 + 10*RANDBETWEEN(0,10)` in  `I12`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited** to add a veeery short alternative (see bottom of the answer)

it's because you have calculation automatic and after `Range("I12").Value = j` statement the worksheets gets calculated and `RANDBETWEEN()` formula you put in J12 gets recalculated and so you don't see it match the `j` you wrote in I12 previously to such last recalculation

you may use this

```
Sub main()
    Dim x As Long, j As Long

    With Range("J12")
        .Formula = "=RANDBETWEEN(100,210)"
        .Value = .Value

        Select Case .Value
            Case 100 To 108
                j = 100

            Case 109 To 118
                j = 110

            Case 119 To 128
                j = 120

            Case 129 To 138
                j = 130

            Case 139 To 148
                j = 140

            Case 149 To 158
                j = 150

            Case 159 To 168
                j = 160

            Case 169 To 178
                j = 170

            Case 179 To 188
                j = 180

            Case 189 To 198
                j = 190

            Case Else
                j = 200

        End Select
    End With
    Range("I12").Value = j
End Sub
```

BTW the same results are achieved by the following code

```
Sub main()    
    With Range("J12")
        .Formula = "=RANDBETWEEN(100,210)"
        .Value = .Value
        .Offset(, -1).Value = IIf(.Value > 208, 200, Int((.Value + 1 - 100) / 10) * 10 + 100)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you for your help. I tried case method before that but ı couldnt find a way to make x values between 100 to 108 ... So ı learned that to. Thank you again.

Comment: Your putatively equivalent code at the bottom isn't equivalent. When `RANDBETWEEN(100,210)` returns 209 or 210 that code computes the value 210 but the other code computes 200. OP's specification introduces a slight bias in favor of the value 200, though that might have been unintended.